# Multiple table update in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

Is it possible to update multiple tables in Oracle with a single query using join? If so, what is the syntax? My colleague said he had done it in MySQL.

**Update**- What I am trying to do is something like this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id SET t1.column1 = 'ABC', t2.column2 = 'BCD' WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have a similar issue where I would like to update a status column in each of two tables with one db call instead of two separate calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What problem are you trying to solve? You cannot use a single update statement in Oracle to update multiple tables, but it is possible using a "Instead-Of" trigger on a view.

Comment: I have only SELECT and UPDATE permission. I cannot create a trigger.

Comment: @Joyce Babu: The view and trigger can be in your own schema.  You shouldn't need any additional privileges on the tables.  (I'm assuming you can at least create objects in your own schema.)

Comment: Thanks jonearles. The project is over, and I no longer have access to the server to test this.